# using EvoSuite plugin for eclipse on Windows 7 OS

Tags: java, eclipse, evosuite

I'm try to use the EvoSuite plugin for eclipse (keplero) on Windows 7 OS. For testing this plugin i download the file ATM.java from the site http://www.evosuite.org/study/ . 
Now when i do right click on the target class -> evoSuite -> Generate JUnit Test Suite eclipse tell me:

Impossible to find the file ATM_ESTest.java

Where i wrong?

PS: if i create the file ATM_ESTest.java the error disappear, but the file not change (no test are write)

Answer (score 1):

This problem can also be found in command line operation.In command line operation,we found jre lacks the jdk's `tools.jar`. If the `jdk1.8/lib/tools.jar` was put into `jre8/lib/`, the problem will be solved.