# Error in generating test cases when using EvoSuite Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, evosuite

When using EvoSuite Eclipse Plugin to generate a test case for a class which extends HttpServlet in a Dynamic Web Project, I am getting the following error.

[image]

Those Chinese characters meanings "**Windows can not find this file  `F:\Java\J2EEWorkspace\EvoSuiteTest\evosuite-tests\com\s...\TestServlet_ESTest.java` . Please try to check the file name again. "**.

The code which will be generated by EvoSuite Eclipse Plugin are

```
package com.servlet;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void service( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse     response ){
        System.out.println("I am a test...");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if we add the Servlet Container jars(eg. the jars in tomcat/lib ) into the project again in spite of the Server Runtime Library which have been added already ,the problem will be solved. I do not know what the reason is. It may be an Evosuite's bug.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can also be found in command line operation.In command line operation,we found jre lacks the jdk's tools.jar. If the jdk1.8/lib/tools.jar was put into jre8/lib/, the problem will be solved.

[using EvoSuite plugin for eclipse on Windows 7 OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31266105/using-evosuite-plugin-for-eclipse-on-windows-7-os)